# Journey mornitoring - stop working when adding marker to map

Tags: android, google-maps

My location app is ok. Now my purpose is to change the app to Journey Monitoring. The idea is getting information from a website containing current latitude and longitude of a vehicle. I added the url request into a runnable. I received **java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread**, **com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)** and  **com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)**. How can I solve this.

Activity:

```
package tri.mylocapp;
//import...
public class MainActivity extends Activity{ 
    GoogleMap googlemap = null;
    LatLng latlng;
    LocationManager lm;
    String provider;
    Location location;
    MarkerOptions marker;
    double lat,lng;
    URL url;
    URLConnection conn;
    String str;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         if (isGooglePlay()){
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         setUpMap();
         }
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlay(){
         int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
         if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Log.d("mytag", "google ok");
            return true;
         }
         else{
            Log.d("mytag","google not ok");
            Toast.makeText(this, "GooglePlay is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
         return false;
         }

    private void setUpMap(){
        if (googlemap == null){
            Log.d("mytag", "googlemap is null, making it available");
            googlemap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (googlemap != null){
                Log.d("mytag", "googlemap is not null");
                googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {             
                    try {
                        url = new URL("http://thinktodo.net/LocationServiceSystem/index.php/location/getLocation?username=1");
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        str = br.readLine();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(str);
                        final double lat = jsonObject.getDouble("lat");
                        final double lng = jsonObject.getDouble("lng");
                        latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)).title("You are here");
                        googlemap.addMarker(marker);
                        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
                        br.close();

                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }               
                    }
                };
                Thread th = new Thread(r);
                th.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

}

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

logcat:

```
04-23 02:49:51.250: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 70084 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 185900 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 136748 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.254: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 87596 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.298: E/Trace(1692): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-180
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at maps.k.o.b(Unknown Source)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at maps.i.g.b(Unknown Source)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at etl.onTransact(SourceFile:167)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addMarker(Unknown Source)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at tri.mylocapp.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:88)
04-23 02:49:51.858: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 206832 bytes, got 16384 
04-23 02:49:51.930: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 190448 bytes, got 97988 
04-23 02:49:51.934: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 92460 bytes, got 49152 
04-23 02:49:51.934: E/SocketStream(112): readFully was waiting for 43308 bytes, got 32768
```

Comment: why not use asynctask and also sopportMapFragment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are modifying the map on a different Thread is should be modified on the UI thread/main thread..

```
                        latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude)).title("You are here");
                        googlemap.addMarker(marker);
                        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));
                        googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
```

That is where the problem came from...

**Solution:**

Use an [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) do all the server connection and parsing on the **doinbackground** and when is it successfull do the modifying of the map on the **postexecute**